# Are solutions to LTI ODE's always a linear combination of complex exponential terms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have

$\ a_n *f^{(n)}(t) + a_{n-1} *f^{(n - 1)}(t) ... + a_0 * f(t) = g(t)$ ,

is $\ f(t) $ a linear combination of complex exponential terms?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: What do you mean by "solutions" ? Is this continuous or discrete time? Update your post with a lot more contect than answering just those two questions.

Comment: Ok, I edited it. I meant continuous time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your $a_i$ are constants. Even in the simplest case, when $g(t)=0$, the answer is "No." If the complementary equation has a root $\alpha $ of multiplicity $\nu>1$ there will be a term $t^{\nu -1}e^{\alpha t}$ in the solution.